# Uninstall program without uninstall file (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall

I downloaded [Julia Pro v.0.621](https://juliacomputing.com/products/juliapro.html) for Windows and installed it.

Accidentally, the package was deleted. I tried to install it again, the installer says:

> JuliaPro is already installed, please uninstall the existing version before continuing

However, when I selected "Uninstall" option in Windows Settings, it's unable to do it since the uninstall file was missing (it's deleted).

I don't remember what I did, but now the program is no longer in "Program and Features" list, still it is not uninstall yet.

So, is there anyway to uninstall a program without the uninstall file? Or specifically to my case, is there any way that I can install Julia again?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  You will find that we are always glad to help, but when you emphasize *"I don't remember what I did"* to cause the issue, that makes it rather difficult to assist you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well. If you have removed the whole install folder of JuliaPro in your hard disk, while the installer still inform you with the message. I think you should clear the Registry information in Reg Editor.

Run "regedit" and find the the Registry information of JuliaPro. Remove the folder and try it again.

Good luck.

Comment: Why do people down vote this? It works!

Comment: @FelixFourcolor Well, I have no idea.. Glad it works. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would try step 3 of [this article](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/10-tips-for-removing-a-program-that-won-t-uninstall-907471) first

> 3. (..) [10AppsManager](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/10appsmanager-windows-10) is a perfect solution; it can cut away those preinstalled applications that can’t be removed (and, indeed, those which can) from a single point. It’s also adept at banishing Windows Store apps without having to use the Windows Store, and can reinstall the apps later on if you wish to have them back.

and if this should not work then consider the other options mentioned in that article (use a backup, use [Revo Uninstaller Free](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/revo-uninstaller-free), modify the registry).

Also trying to install another Julia Pro version from [the older releases](https://juliacomputing.com/products/olderreleases/olderrelease.html) might be worth a try.